# Removing an element before the object passed in as the parameter in a Singly Linked List

Tags: java, algorithm, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to write a method for to remove an element before the object passed in as a parameter in a Singly Linked List.

So far I have this, but honestly I'm completely lost.

```
public void removeElementBefore(Object o) {

  Node n = new Node(o);
  Node crt = head;

  // trying to find the element right before the parameter
  while(crt.next != n)
    crt = crt.next;

  // getting the new content
  n = crt.next.content;

  return n;
  }
}
```

More of the program for context: method to remove last element in the list

```
public Object removeLast() throws EmptyListException {

    if (head == null) throw new EmptyListException();

    Object o;

    // If there is only one element, we need to modify the head of the list
    if (head.next == null) {
      o = head.content;
      head.content = null;
      head = null;
      return o;
    }

    // We need to go to the second-to-last element
    Node crt = head;
    while (crt.next.next != null)
      crt = crt.next;

    // Now get the content
    o = crt.next.content;

    // Remove all references that are not needed
    crt.next.content = null;
    crt.next = null;

    // And we're done
    return o;
  }
```

Comment: I recommend adding more of the program for context.

Comment: @KyleSpencer Added another method

Comment: So what exactly is the problem with this, does is throw an exception, does it just not work? Also it would be nice to see the whole program to see how you structure it.

Comment: Your method isn't even valid Java syntax. It also contains a `return` although it is a `void` method. It does not delete anything. And it is O(n) when it could be O(1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```java
public Object removeElementBefore(Object o) {
    if (o == null)
        return null;

    Node prev = head;
    Node crt = prev == null ? null : prev.next;
    if (crt == null)
        return null;

    // trying to find the element right before the parameter
    while(crt.next != null && !o.equals(crt.next.content)) {
        prev = prev.next;
        crt = crt.next;
    }

    if (crt.next == null)
        return null;

    // remove crt node from list
    prev.next = crt.next;
    crt.next = null;

    // return the removed content
    return crt.content;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! could you explain to me what the "Node crt = prev == null ? null : prev.next;" line does?

Comment: @user2980566 Are you familiar with the conditional ternary operator `?:`? If not you can read about it [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:)

Comment: @NiklasB. just curious, if we wanted to remove the node after the parameter, could we adjust the while loop and make it o.equals(crt.next.content)?

Comment: @user2980566 I'm not the author of this answer, but I guess in that case it would be `while (crt != null && !o.equals(crt.content))`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a non-Java specific algorithm (not necessarily completely compact). You should be able to translate it into Java code.

Given linked list **L** and item to remove **item**.

```
cur = L.head
if (cur == item)
   L.head = cur.next
   return
prev = cur
cur = cur.next
while (cur != item):
    if NOT (cur.next exists):
        // cur is the end of the list, so the item doesn't exist in this list
        return
    prev = cur
    cur = cur.next

// If you reach this point, the desired item has been found, and prev
// precedes it in the list
prev.next = cur.next
```

Comment: This will actually remove the item passed in, not the item before it, but the structure should still hold as a good starting point.

Comment: @NiklasB Can you elaborate?

Comment: never mind, that would only work if you get a reference to the node, not the object.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void removeElementBefore(Node before) {
    if (before == null) return;
    Node n = head;

    if (n.next == before) {
        head = n.next;
        return;
    }

    while (n.next.next != before) { 
        if (n.next.next == null) return;
        n = n.next;
    }
    n.next = n.next.next;
}
```